# Custom Button in android Studio

Tags: button, custom-controls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlNq3.png)[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6tHF.png)

Hi friends, I am new to android development. I want to create a button in the above screenshot model. Can any one help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can download that image and use the imageButton in xml

For that just, copy the downloaded image to drawable folder and use the code

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/imageName"
    android:id="@+id/image_button"/>
```